# Замена ссылок с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ссылки

Вопрос, наверное, из разряда элементарных, но в JS я как-то совсем не очень.

Как создать кнопку, заменяющую все ссылки определенного вида на странице? То есть, допустим, на страницу вставлены картинки с адресами вида:

```
<img src="http://example.com/1.png">
```

А нужно по нажатию на кнопку заменить их на адреса вида

```
<img src="http://test.ru/1.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На jQuery

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    var new_src = 'http://i.imgur.com/MiLB4h5.gif';
    $('img').attr('src', new_src);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vx71fz7o/5/

на JS

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = 'http://i.imgur.com/MiLB4h5.gif';
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vx71fz7o/11/

**UPD**

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
var old_base_url = 'http://i.imgur.com/';
var new_base_url = 'http://test.ru/';
$('img').each(function(){      
    var new_src = $(this).attr('src').replace(old_base_url, new_base_url);
    $(this).attr('src', new_src);
});    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vx71fz7o/16/

Comment: Не совсем то, что я спрашивал. Мне нужно заменить только базовый адрес (домен) в ссылках на картинки.

Comment: Тогда смотрите апдейт.